# Extract Specific Text from a String using functions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I had these strings that has no particular patterns:

```
- ControlF Job Name: WEB_GG_WPP_PRD_C_C_ELASTICOWL Status: Ended Not Ok  Odate: 04/20/2019 Run Count: 2

- ControlF: WEB_WP_UPP_PRD_C_C_ELASTICOWL  Ended Not Ok  Odate: 4/21  RunCount: 2

-  ControlF: WEB_PP_BPP_PRD_C_D_ELASTICWEEKLY  Status: Ended not OK   Odate: 4/29   Run count: 1

- CONTROLF:   Job Name: WEB_PP_EDM_PRD_T_C_HP1_CTGGDALTA Status: Ended NOT OK Odate: 6/26/2017 RunCount: 2

- CONTROLF:   Job Name: WEB_EZ_APP_PRD_C_D_3RDPANTYUPAC Status: Ended NOT OK Odate: 6/16/2016 RunCount: 1
```

I need to extract these `WEB_*` string (e.g. `WEB_GG_WPP_PRD_C_C_ELASTICOWL`) from these using Excel. I tried using Text-to-Columns, but the string I need is placed all over the sheet. So my questions will be:

1. If using Text-to-Columns, how can I pull only the `WEB_*` string?
2. How will it be if I'll just use formulas?
3. What will be the code for this using VBA?

Thanks!

EDIT: Attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEWfA.png) for more examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the Job for You:

Function : `=MID(D6,FIND("WEB",D6,1),FIND("Status",D6,1)-FIND("WEB",D6,1))`

- Updated Function to use
- `MID(D6,FIND("WEB",D6,1),FIND(" ",D6,FIND("WEB",D6,1))-FIND("WEB",D6,1))`

[image]

---

You can run same function on `Range` in VBA to get this result in a Loop.

Comment: @kkshinichi .. I realised and changed the Answer accordingly .. Use the new function

Comment: Next word after the string is also variable. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @kkshinichi .. Edit your question and explain your full problem. As far as I can understand this function will get you your results.

Comment: @kkshinichi ... Added the new Function for your variable next word.

Comment: If ever there's nothing after the text I want to filter (e.g. ControlF: WEEB_US_AVP_PRO_D_E_UTILIZE), it returns a #VALUE. How to avoid that?

Comment: @kkshinichi .. Didn't understand what you meant to say here. I would suggest you to post another question. It's not accepted in community to update questions. :)